# Is something like 'onImport' exists in js?

Tags: javascript

There are two files

**file 1**

```
import { getSingleRunningPromiseFunction } from "./main"

const getSingleRunningPromise = getSingleRunningPromiseFunction.bind({
    singlePromise: undefined,
    promise: undefined,
    running: false,
});

getSingleRunningPromise()
```

**file 2**

```
import { getSingleRunningPromiseFunction } from "./main"

const getSingleRunningPromise = getSingleRunningPromiseFunction.bind({
    singlePromise: undefined,
    promise: undefined,
    running: false,
});

getSingleRunningPromise()
```

I'd like to extract bind logic, but this variant will share the binded between all consumers

```
export const getSingleRunningPromise = getSingleRunningPromiseFunction.bind({
    singlePromise: undefined,
    promise: undefined,
    running: false,
});
```

Is it possible to extract bind and don't create a function? E.g. do `import { getSingleRunningPromise } from "./main"` but for each consumer provide unique `this context`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `bind` to create multiple different `this` values. I think you are looking for

```
export function getSingleRunningPromise(...args) {
    return getSingleRunningPromiseFunction.call({
        singlePromise: undefined,
        promise: undefined,
        running: false,
    }, ...args)
}
```

Comment: yes, it is very close, as I understand, calling this twice, I will get two different instances of single running promise. The problem here that somtimes, it can be provided like anonymous function, e.g. `getSingleRunninePromise(async () => ...)`; Technically this can be another anonymous function, but practically not, f.e. in React, on each render the new anonymous function would be created. So I like be able to return the same instance of the promise for some calls. In react they have `useCallback`, I think I want smth similar.

Comment: @Nikita "*calling this twice, I will get two different instances*" - is that not what you wanted? I thought you were looking to avoid a "*variant will share the binded between all consumers*".

Comment: yes, but I also want be able to save this context as singleton between calls, and currently this is an issue) I will try to play with your sample, have feeling that maybe can adopt it.

Comment: @Nikita Maybe I'm missing what your `getSingleRunningPromiseFunction`  does, but if you want to sometimes share to object and sometimes not, just put the original `bind` call in a function.

Comment: sometimes one consumer can call it more than one time with same promise, and in this case need to make `this` static between calls of one consumer, because this is single running promise.

Comment: I will definitely give a feedback later, thank you)

Comment: Finally, I have used your solution :) But still haven't achieved the initial goal, you can check my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

Final solution for react, that should be working for now.

```
export function getSingleRunningPromise<TResult>(getPromise: (...args: any[]) => Promise<TResult>) {
    return getSingleRunningPromiseFunction.call(
        {
            singlePromise: undefined,
            promise: undefined,
            running: false,
        },
        getPromise
    );
}

export function useSingleRunningPromise<TResult>(getPromise: (...args: any[]) => Promise<TResult>, deps: any[]) {
    return useCallback(getSingleRunningPromise(getPromise), deps);
}
```

Usage

```
// react class component
class MyComponent extends Component {
     private promise = getSingleRunningPromise(async () => ...);
     render() {
         return <button onClick={this.promise}>Click me</button>
     }
}

// react hooks
export function MyComponent() {
    const promise = useSingleRunningPromise(async () => ...);
    return <button onClick={promise}>Click me</button>
}
```

PS. I was trying to be able to write in function component `<button onClick={getSingleRunningPromise(async () => )}>Click me</button>`, but currently have no time. Was playing here https://jsbin.com/mizevor/edit?js,console. The desired output to see 1,2 (or 0,1) for all cases. And don't want to add any decorators on functions. Later will see is it possible.
[image]